# Can't get child views to load in AngularJS with ui-router

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm trying to understand the concept of using the ui-router (v0.2.10) with AngularJS (v1.2.15) through converting an old project that previously used ngRoute and have been unable to figure out why it isn't working. I have an ASP.NET MVC website that shows the base page with something similar to the following:

**index.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-US" ng-app="home">
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    </head>
    <body>
      <div ui-view></div>
      @Scripts.Render(*all the angular, jquery and other script references here)
    </body>
  </html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('home') ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/");
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

var root = {
  name: 'root',
  url: '/',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: '/Scripts/home/templates/root.html',
  controller: 'RootController'
};

var home = {
  name: 'root.home',
  url: '/home',
  parent: root,
  templateUrl: 'Scripts/home/templates/home.html',
  controller: 'HomeController'
};

$stateProvider
  .state(root)
  .state(home);

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
};
```

**rootCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('home').controller('RootController', function() {
});
```

**homeCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('home').controller('HomeController', function() {
});
```

**root.html**

```
<navbar/>
<div class="wrapper" style="padding-top:25px;margin-bottom:20px">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
<footer/>
```

**navbar.js**

```
angular.module('home').directive('navbar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/Scripts/home/templates/directives/navbar.html'
  };
});
```

The navbar directive template simply contains the bootstrap navbar.

**footer.js**

```
angular.module('home').directive('footer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/Scripts/home/templates/directives/footer.html'
  };
});
```

Except that nothing shows up on the page except for the CSS references at the top, the following, and then the javascript references at the bottom:

Why doesn't the root.html view show up on the screen when I load up the page? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per another answer on this site, one cannot self-close the tags for custom directives. Thus, if I change the tags in root.html to the following:

```
<navbar></navbar>
<div class="wrapper" style="padding-top:25px;margin-bottom:20px">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

It works fine.